# windows update no longer updating the .net framework 4.8

Tags: windows-update, .net-framework

so far i had been relying on `windows update` to also install the latest patches for the `.net framework 4.8`.
but this is no longer happening on my machine with "windows 10 pro" (running in workgroup mode).

here's a simplified list of the windows update history of that machine:

```
 - 2020-xx-xx windows 10
 - 2020-08-14 .net update 2020-08 KB4569745
 - 2020-08-14 windows 10 upgrade to 2004
 - 2020-10-20 .net update 2020-10 KB4578968
 - 2021-01-19 windows 10 upgrade to 20H2
 - 2021-02-23 .net update 2021-02 KB4601050 (<------)
 - 2021-09-21 windows 10 upgrade to 21H1
 - 2021-10-27 windows 10 21H1 cumulative update KB5006670
 - 2021-11-03 update for windows 10 21H1 KB5005463
```

at the time of writing it's *november* 2021.
the last .net framework update (`KB4601050`) was installed in *february* 2021.
for example: the machine still has "System.Windows.Forms.dll" with file version "4.8.4270.0".

there have been more recent .net framework updates. for example cumulative update `KB5005539` (october 2021).
but windows update is just not finding and installing those.

what could be the reason those automatic updates are no longer working?

--

a note to the comments:
i'm *not* talking about the registry entries below NDP (which for me shows up as "4.8.04084").
instead, i'm talking about "cumulative updates" that are updating the individual .net framework assemblies. for example: go to "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319" and check the file version attribute of "System.Windows.Forms.dll"
and at top level i'm simply looking at the "windows update history".

--

**update:**

the closest match that i have found is in the discussion at: https://www.askwoody.com/forums/topic/net-update-confusion/

discussion summary:
at the time of writing the KB4601056 / KB4601050 (february 2021) was the last one classified by microsoft as .net `security` update.
all later cumulative updates are classified as .net `quality and reliability improvement` updates.

depending on how you have configured your "windows update" service, the latter category will not be shown / downloaded by windows update.

--

so the challenge might be to pick the right configuration:

- i do *not* want any "preview" updates
- but i do want updates for quality and reliability (with a delay of 7 days after they have been released)

unfortunately, the following settings in "gpedit.msc -> Windows Update for Business" still don't make the .net framework updates show up:
[image]

so maybe after all it's still some glitch or bug in the supersedence chain of the .NET Framework updates?

Comment: My Net is 4.8.04084 per checking the version  with Powershell.   My System is updating properly. Open Powershell as admin an type:   Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' -Recurse | Get-ItemProperty -Name version -EA 0 | Where { $_.PSChildName -Match '^(?!S)\p{L}'} | Select PSChildName, version

 to get the version you have.

Comment: I checked a Windows 11 Pro Production machine with the Powershell command and that version is 4.8.04161.  This is a new machine so there are no earlier .NET versions.  Nothing is as new as 4270.   Did you try to update .NET manually?

Comment: Edit your question to indicate what the last cumulative patch for Windows was actually installed. Additionally provide what the last update for .NET ( the patch number). I want to do some research

Comment: Checking my own system it does not appear you are missing any updates. Be sure you are looking under "Other Updates". Since you have not indicated you have failed updates, I can only assume, the update you are asking about is actually installed and you are looking under "Quality Updates" instead of "Other Updates'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that discussion at https://www.askwoody.com/forums/topic/net-update-confusion/ `Susan Bradley` says it all (bold emphasis mine):

> .NET’s are very **confusing** in how they are packaged and handled by
> Windows update.
>
> If you leave your machine and don’t set any group policy settings, you
> get updates that have bug fixes but not any new security updates.
>
> If you set any of the normal *deferrals*, you get treated like a
> “business” patcher and only get offered when a .NET update gets
> released with a new **security** update.
>
> What you are experiencing is indeed “normal”.

as per my understanding those "deferrals" making one being treated as a "business" patcher are the following:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"BranchReadinessLevel"=dword:00000010
"DeferFeatureUpdates"=dword:00000001
"DeferFeatureUpdatesPeriodInDays"=dword:0000005a
"DeferQualityUpdates"=dword:00000001
"DeferQualityUpdatesPeriodInDays"=dword:00000007
"ManagePreviewBuilds"=dword:00000001
"ManagePreviewBuildsPolicyValue"=dword:00000000
"PauseFeatureUpdatesStartTime"=""
"PauseQualityUpdatesStartTime"=""
```

with the above settings i'm *not* getting the regular bug fixes (quality updates) for the .net framework.
so it seems it was **not** possible to achieve all of the following:

```
 - under no circumstances i want "preview" updates!
 - i do want "security" updates (ideally delayed by 7 days)
 - i do want "quality" updates (ideally delayed by 30 days)
 - i do want "feature" updates (ideally delayed by 3 months)
```

what a shame ...

so in case we're interested in a specific .net quality update, we need to download the MSU from the microsoft update catalog and install manually.